# Mule 4 : Scripting : How to debug errors in Mule 4 Groovy Script?

Tags: groovy, mule4

I am having a groovy script in the "Execute Script" component in Mule 4 application.
I am getting the Null Pointer Exception while executing the script.
Is there any way we can debug the script line by line or get the exact error from the Mule error for this groovy script?

Comment: Debug it outside of mule

Answer (score 1):

Use Groovy's println() function to print variables values and messages to know where the execution of the script is at that point in time.

Anypoint Studio debugger doesn't step inside Groovy scripts, or any scripting.